# Android - replace the built in dialler screen with custom made one

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm working on an 'Emergency Dialler' for a school which will have numbers that I don't want the user to see (as they are kids and if they see the numbers they are likely to play havoc with them!)

After much googling I found an article on reflecting the "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony" class, which seems to have brought me closer to dealing with calls, but the "call(String phonenumber)" method brings up the installed dialler screen which displays the number! How can I create my own that does not display the number?

edit: here is a code snippet of my dial method -

```
private void performDial(String numberString){

    if (!numberString.equals("")) {
     TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        try {
            // Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's
            // ITelephony getter
            Log.v(TAG, "Get getTeleService...");
            Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService =(ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
            //

            telephonyService.dial(numberString);//only opens dial screen, does not place call
            telephonyService.call(numberString);//places call, but opens built in dial screen which shows dialled number

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG,
                    "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception object: " + e);
        }
    }
    else
     {
         errorOut("Empty number field");
     }

}
```

Comment: You do realize that they just have to look at the call log to see what numbers they called, right?  Even if you find a way to obfuscate it on the phone, there is still the paper bill, etc.

Comment: I have made a custom launcher which gives me control over the app drawer (I've hidden all the system apps including the dialler) and the phones don't actually belong to the students so they will never see the paper bill

Comment: If you are going to use undocumented features, you might as well go whole hog and create a custom ROM.

Comment: That was going to be the plan eventually, I still need the dialler screen to hide the number though...

Comment: What about blue tooth devices?  There are a multitude of blue tooth devices that will give you dialling control and access to the phones call log.  Are you going to prevent them from pairing the phones with blue tooth devices as well?  If they can use the phones to make phone calls they can hit redial.  At this point you are no longer really handing them a phone, but rather a fancy, expensive pager that only calls you.  Why not just give them those bracelets they give to old people?

Comment: haha well a bracelet won't come with all the fancy educational apps you can get on android :P
I mentioned before my custom home screen/launcher doesn't have any system apps visible, and they won't be able to add any apps unless they know the master password

Comment: I guess I am still confused as to what exactly you are trying to prevent.  You say that giving the kids the actual number would be Bad.  Why?  Are you afraid they would prank call it?  They could do that with the phones using your custom dial app.  You could counter by saying but then you would know which kid's phone made the call, but that doesn't solve the "I left my phone unattended on the bench while I went to get lunch" excuse.  Are you afraid they will make random calls with the phones?  The carrier can impose blocks.  You seem to be reaching for an overly complicated solution.